# Confluent_kafka Producer does not publish messages into topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I tried to install Kafka on my Raspberry. And test it on 'hello-kafka' topic:

```
~ $ /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic hello-kafka
>Test message 1
>Test message 2
>Test message 3
>^Z
[4]+  Stopped                 /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic hello-kafka
$ /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic hello-kafka --from-beginning
Test message 1
Test message 2
Test message 3
^CProcessed a total of 3 messages
```

Then I tried to check that server works from another machine.
Checking zookeeper:

```
(venv)$ telnet 192.168.1.10 2181
Trying 192.168.1.10...
Connected to 192.168.1.10.
Escape character is '^]'.
srvr
Zookeeper version: 3.6.0--b4c89dc7f6083829e18fae6e446907ae0b1f22d7, built on 02/25/2020 14:38 GMT
Latency min/avg/max: 0/0.8736/59
Received: 10146
Sent: 10149
Connections: 2
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x96
Mode: standalone
Node count: 139
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

And Kafka:

```
(venv) $ telnet 192.168.1.10 9092
Trying 192.168.1.10...
Connected to 192.168.1.10.
Escape character is '^]'.
tets
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Then I wrote a Python script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from confluent_kafka import Producer


def callback(err, msg):
    if err is not None:
        print(f'Failed to deliver message: {str(msg)}: {str(err)}')
    else:
        print(f'Message produced: {str(msg)}')


config = {
            'bootstrap.servers': '192.168.1.10:9092'
        }

producer = Producer(config)
producer.produce('hello-kafka', value=b"Hello from Python", callback=callback)
producer.poll(5)
```

There is script output (no any prints):

```
(venv) $ python kafka-producer.py 
(venv) $ python kafka-producer.py 
(venv) $
```

And no new messages in Kafka:

```
$ /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic hello-kafka --from-beginning
Test message 1
Test message 2
Test message 3
^CProcessed a total of 3 messages
$ ^C
```

Somebody can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct fix is to update your broker configuration in `server.properties` to set the advertised listener correctly. If your client cannot resolve `raspberrypi` then change the advertised listener to something that your client *can* reach, i.e. the IP address:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.10:9092
```

Changing the `/etc/hosts` file on your client is a workaround that for a test project with a Raspberry Pi is fine, but as a general best practice should be discouraged (because the client will break as soon as it's moved to another machine which *doesn't* have the `/etc/hosts` hack)

Comment: Thank You, Robin! I made changes after Your explanation, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I turned on log and saw next message:

```
WARNING:kafka.conn:DNS lookup failed for raspberrypi:9092, exception was [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known. Is your advertised.listeners (called advertised.host.name before Kafka 9) correct and resolvable?
ERROR:kafka.conn:DNS lookup failed for raspberrypi:9092 (AddressFamily.AF_UNSPEC)
```

Then I added to /etc/hosts on client machine next string:

```
192.168.1.10 raspberrypi
```

And it completely fix this situation.